# Save Layout to bitmap(Xamarin)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, bitmap, xamarin.android

I have layout and need to save it to bitmap

here is code

```
public void Save()
{
    LinearLayout view = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.badge);

    view.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;
    view.BuildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap layout = view.GetDrawingCache(true);

}
```

I set breakpoint to  `Bitmap layout = view.GetDrawingCache(true);` and I see that's layout is null.

Where is my mistake, how to save layout to bitmap?

**UPDATE**

I try to save view to bitmap like this

```
public  Bitmap CreateBitmapFromView(View view, bool autoScale = true)
    {
        var wasDrawingCacheEnabled = view.DrawingCacheEnabled;
        view.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;
        view.BuildDrawingCache(autoScale);
        var bitmap2 = view.GetDrawingCache(autoScale);
        view.DrawingCacheEnabled = wasDrawingCacheEnabled;
        return bitmap2;

    }
```

All ok, bitmap2 is returning.

But also I need to save it to SD

I wrote method like this

```
public  Bitmap CreateBitmapFromView(View view, bool autoScale = true)
    {
        var wasDrawingCacheEnabled = view.DrawingCacheEnabled;
        view.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;
        view.BuildDrawingCache(autoScale);
        var bitmap2 = view.GetDrawingCache(autoScale);
        view.DrawingCacheEnabled = wasDrawingCacheEnabled;
        var sdCardPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
        var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(sdCardPath, "test.png");
        var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
        bitmap2.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
        return bitmap2;

    }
```

And have this error.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change it to something likes this :

```
public Bitmap CreateBitmapFromView(View view, bool autoScale = true)
{
    var wasDrawingCacheEnabled = view.DrawingCacheEnabled;
    view.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;
    view.BuildDrawingCache(autoScale);
    var bitmap = view.GetDrawingCache(autoScale);
    view.DrawingCacheEnabled = wasDrawingCacheEnabled;
    return bitmap;
}
```

**UPDATE**

try to define `var bitmap2` as global variable

```
public  Bitmap CreateBitmapFromView(View view, bool autoScale = true)
    {
        var wasDrawingCacheEnabled = view.DrawingCacheEnabled;
        view.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;
        view.BuildDrawingCache(autoScale);
        view.DrawingCacheEnabled = wasDrawingCacheEnabled;
        var sdCardPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
        var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(sdCardPath, "test.png");
        var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
        bitmap2.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
        return bitmap2;
    }
```

Comment: And how program will understood what layout needs to be saved as btmap?

Comment: `public Bitmap CreateBitmapFromView(View view, bool autoScale = true)` you can pass the view parameter there in that method

Comment: so my View in method will this `LinearLayout view = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.badge);` I will pass Linear Layout?

Comment: you can pass that view to the method that i have writed in the answer

Comment: Okay, I understood that. Also one question,I need to save bitmap to SD

I have code 
`var sdCardPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
            var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(sdCardPath, "test.png");
            var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
            bitmap2.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
            stream.Close();`

How I can save bitmap from your method?

Comment: you can add thoose lines of code in the method body to save it on sdcard ... If you find it helpfull please mark as solution or upvote

Comment: Hm I added but have this `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`. I write method like this `var sdCardPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
            var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(sdCardPath, "test.png");
            var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
            bitmap2.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
            return bitmap2;`

Comment: can you please post it as new answer in stack ? i will be more readable bcos i dont understand nothing here at the comments :)